# what's the best way to make sure user can't edit other users data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using tank_auth on codeigniter to manage the users login.

There are several pages where user can edit some of their account specific parameters, I'm wondering what would be the safest and easiest way to make sure each user only can edit their own stuff?

Obvious way is to check if user is editing their stuff on every page, but maybe there is something easier?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user->id == $localUser->id)
    // Can edit
```

You probably saving the user in the database with id, so when you load the 'local' user which is the actual logged in user. Take he's ID or username or whatever unique info you got on the user. and compare it to the author of the the 'stuff' ..

Comment: Try adding a bit more text. What does this do? Where does this go? In every file? In a specific one? etc.

Comment: Sure, added more info.